# Why not allow quoted arguments in macros

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp, quote

I've asked this question recentely on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnlisp/comments/eausih/whether_to_allow_qutoted_arguments_in_macros/) but I thought perhaps I'd get a better answer here.

Often macros I write take either a symbol or a list of symbols and sometimes these symbols represent a variable or a function. And in these cases I'm tempted write the macros so that their arguments can be quoted or sharquoted. Here's a concrete example:

In emacs lisp the function add-hook adds HOOK-FN to a list named HOOK.

```lisp
(add-hook 'hook #'hook-fn)
```

Often you want to add several items to HOOK or you want HOOK-FN to several hooks, but add-hook only takes in one hook or one hook-fn at a time. So, I made a macro for this called add-hook! which can accept multiple arguments.

```lisp
(add-hook! hook-name (fn1 fn2 fn3))

;; or

(add-hook! (hook-name1 hook-name2) hook-fn)
```

I am inclined to allow arugments to the macro to be quoted or sharpquoted. Just as they would be in a function call.

```lisp
(add-hook! 'hook-name #'fn)
```

To do this I'd use a function like this to strip off the quotes from each argument.

```
(defun unquote (form)
  "Unquote a form if it is quoted, otherwise return form."
  (if (member (car-safe it) '(quote function))
      (cadr form)
    form))
```

I am inclided to do this because quoting and sharpquoting (1) makes it clear whether I mean a function or a symbol and (2) triggers my autocompletion, which helps me type the function or symbol faster.

However, I am under the impression that this is not the convention in lisp. Why? Are there good reasons why you should not allow quoted arguments in macros?

Comment: I think the one-word answer is 'taste'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can do that, but it looks a little strange, because it mixes visual signals that say “Function here, normal evaluation” and “Macro here, special evaluation”.

Why don't you make `add-hook-fns` a (quite simple) function, just like `add-hook` is?  Then all the quoting naturally falls into place and is even required.

```
(defun add-hook-fns (hook fns)
  (dolist (fn fns)
    (add-hook hook fn)))
```

This would then look on invocation like this:

```
(add-hook-fns 'some-hook (list #'foo #'bar #'baz))
```

If you don't want that explicit call to `list` in there, you can use a macro to eliminate just that:

```
(defmacro add-hook-fns* (hook fns)
  `(add-hook-fns ,hook (list ,@fns)))
```

Et voilà:

```
(add-hook-fns* 'some-hook (#'foo #'bar #'baz))
```

However, I don't recommend that, see reasons at the start.

Instead, I'd still use just a function, but with rest parameters:

```
(defun add-hook-fns (hook &rest fns)
  (dolist (fn fns)
    (add-hook hook fn)))
```

Now:

```
(add-hook-fns 'some-hook #'foo #'bar #'baz)
```